# How can i highlight child nodes in organisational highcharts angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to build a chart using organisation module of highcharts in angular.

Currently, I am creating it by using static data but it should be created based on api result.

Also i want whenever any node is clicked than an active class should be applied to this and its child. I have used click event for this and class is being applied but css is not reflecting.

below is my line of code can you please suggest

comp.ts

```
export class OrganisationComponent implements OnInit {
  public options: any = {
    chart: {
      height: 600,
      inverted: true
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Org Chart'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'organization',
      name: 'Highsoft',
      keys: ['from', 'to'],
      cursor: 'pointer',
      events: {
        click: function (event) {
          event.point.linksFrom.forEach(element => {
            if(element.toNode){
              if(element.toNode.linksFrom){
                element.toNode.linksFrom.forEach(innerElement => {
                  innerElement.toNode.dataLabel.addClass('active');
                })
              }
            }
            element.toNode.dataLabel.addClass('active');
          });
        }
    },
      data: [
        ['PMO', 'TM'],
        ['TM', 'D1'],
        ['TM', 'D2'],
        ['TM', 'D3'],
        ['D1', 'Intern'],
      ],
      nodes: [
        {
          id: 'PMO',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Project Manager'
        },
        {
          id: 'TM',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Team Lead'
        },
        {
          id: 'D1',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Developer 1'
        },
        {
          id: 'D2',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Developer 2'
        },
        {
          id: 'D3',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Developer 3'
        },
        {
          id: 'Intern',
          icon: 'account_circle',
          name: 'Intern'
        },
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        nodeFormat : `{point.name}`
      }
    }],

  };
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options); // organization

  }

}
```

**.html**

**.css**

```
.active {
   font-size: 22px;
   color: red;
}
```

stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bar-highcharts-bnom1n

1. I am stuck how can i make it work with api data
2. how to apply active class on all child nodes and clicked node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Add styles in style.css as per other answer for css , for n level highlight try this recursive approach.
// update your click event as per below

```
  events: {
        click: function (event) {
          event.point.linksFrom.forEach(element => {
            highlightPoints(element);
            element.toNode.dataLabel.addClass('active');
          });
          function highlightPoints(element){
                if(element.toNode){
              if(element.toNode.linksFrom){
                element.toNode.linksFrom.forEach(innerElement => {
                  highlightPoints(innerElement);
                  innerElement.toNode.dataLabel.addClass('active');
                })
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also can you please suggest how can create chart by using data from organisation service instead static data

Comment: sure will try to add a demo and share ,meanwhile i will recommend if you have 2-3 or types of charts to be added in project  use-- package --  highcharts-angular  this link may help , it will be alot easier to handle update then as well ---- https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fcomponents%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.html

Comment: Here you can find a simple demo that will show you how you could get data from the service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-service. I can see that you are not using the highcharts-angular wrapper. I will encourage you to check it out, it will make everything easier. You can find more information here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: You can even make it simpler and create your chartOptions directly on the constructor (this approach will allow you to skip the update that I performed on ngOnInit in my previous demo): https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-service-2

Answer (score 1):

To active child nodes by clicking on parent, do the following:

add .active style in style.css

```
.active {
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the updated stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bar-highcharts-ulvycw?file=src%2Fapp%2Forganisation%2Forganisation.component.css)

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want each child to be updated by active class this only updates till 2 level

Comment: As i can see in  demo , all child nodes are getting updated by clicking on parent.

Comment: if you click on project manager you can see grandchild Intern is not highlighted

Comment: I know the reason it is because I have not added forEach loop for grandchild in click event but I am trying a solution to make it generalize as data will come from API end so it can be of any depth

Comment: Okay got it now, can you just check my updated demo, its working now for all childs

Comment: thanks for your answer but if I click on developer 1 still it will add active class to it's parent and siblings which should not be the case... it Should not applied to clicked item and it's child

Comment: sorry my bad i forgot to check that, can you check once i updated demo again.